# Cambridge Press pure maths book contents

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I am revisiting maths after studying it at school some time ago, I'm planning on using the [Cambridge Press books](http://education.cambridge.org/subject/mathematics/cambridge-advanced-mathematics-for-ocr) as they worked well for me before.  However I am confused as to what is covered in their pure books (can't find their table of contents anywhere online, and I did not study pure at school):

- Further Pure 1 (Published 2004)
- Further Pure 2 & 3 (Published 2005)
- Pure Mathematics 3 (Published 2000)
- Pure Mathematics 4 (Published 2001)

Could all four books be studied, or is there significant overlap between them?  If anyone could point me in the direction of a table of contents that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Table of Contents of Pure 2 and 3 at http://www.cambridge.org/aus/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521530125;

Introduction; 1. The motion of projectiles; 2. Moments; 3. Centre of mass; 4. Rigid objects in equilibrium; 5. Elastic strings and springs; Revision exercise 1; 6. Motion round a circle; 7. Geometrical methods; 8. Centres of mass of special shapes; 9. Linear motion with variable forces; 10. Strategies for solving problems; Revision exercise 2; Practice examinations; Answers; Index; Formulae

I'd be very surprised if you couldn't find the others at that website.

Comment: That is a different book and series entirely.  Looking at the contents of that book, in the OCR series that would be mechanics, not pure.  While the table of contents is not on the Cambridge website or Amazon, I seem to have found some of the books at powells.com, I will post a complete answer once I have compared them for others to benifit.

Comment: You could also try email to the publisher.

Comment: I suspect that I will just be told each set of books target a different OCR exam paper, but I may be proved wrong, have sent them an email...